# Github actions incorrectly thinks variable is a secret and so does not set outputs

Tags: github, amazon-ec2, github-actions, masking

A step in my workflow file will return some IDs of EC2 instances in my aws account and then i set these IDs as a github output to be used in other jobs in my workflow file

I have done this in many workflows and step will return something like this:

```
["i-0d945b001544f2614","i-0b90ba69d37aad78c"]
```

However, in one workflow file github is masking the IDs as it thinks it is a secret for some reason, so it will return:

```
["i-***2d571abc6d7d***4ef","i-***186ce12c5cd8e744"]
```

Therefore i get this error message on the workflow job summary:

```
Skip output 'instanceIDs' since it may contain secret.
```

And so the other jobs in my workflow file that rely on this output will fail as github won't set an output.

I have tried to use base64 as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73476075/how-to-not-mask-output-in-github-actions) but i haven't been able to get that to work

Is there any other work around?

Comment: You are in luck, you need to replace your secrets with variables: https://github.blog/changelog/2023-01-10-github-actions-support-for-configuration-variables-in-workflows/

Comment: @aknosis if you don't mind, I posted an answer based on the link you've shared :)
It may be useful for others who will search for a solution in similar cases

Comment: @aknosis - thanks! very lucky timing!

Answer (score 2):

Recently, GitHub released a new feature - [configuration variables in workflows](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-01-10-github-actions-support-for-configuration-variables-in-workflows/).

*Configuration variables allow you to store your non sensitive data as plain text variables that can be reused across your workflows in your repository or organization.*

*You can define variables at Organization, Repository, or Environment level based on your requirement.*

These variables are accessible from the workflow by [`vars` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#vars-context).

**Example:**

```
jobs:
  display-variables:
    runs-on: ${{ vars.RUNNER }}
    steps:
    - name: Use variables
      run: |
        echo "Repository variable : ${{ vars.REPOSITORY_VAR }}"
        echo "Organization variable : ${{ vars.ORGANIZATION_VAR }}"
```

In this example, we have the following configuration variables: `RUNNER`, `REPOSITORY_VAR`, `ORGANIZATION_VAR`. As opposed to the repository secrets, the values of these variables won't be masked.

For more details, see the [Defining configuration variables for multiple workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#defining-configuration-variables-for-multiple-workflows).

Comment: thank you! this alternative is working for me now