# How to unmask values (e.g. accessToken) of `az account get-access-token` in GitHub Actions workflow?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, cloud, azure-cli

When requesting an access token with `az account get-access-token ...` in GitHub Actions, the output (e.g. `accessToken`) is masked, even in the raw logs.

How can I unmask the output, so that I'm able to inspect the values for PoC work?

`.github/workflows/azure-login.yaml`:

```
name: Run Azure Login with OIDC
on: [push]

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "Az CLI login"
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          allow-no-subscriptions: true
      - name: "Run az commands"
        run: |
          az account get-access-token --resource=${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }} --scope=api://${{ secrets.AZURE_TARGET_API }}/.default
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I see my git secrets unencrypted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63003669/how-can-i-see-my-git-secrets-unencrypted)

Answer (score 1):

> **I agree  and Thanks to @rickvdbosch commented [SO LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63003669/how-can-i-see-my-git-secrets-unencrypted) answer by possan**  When I tried the below code with answer recommended by possan in above SO link to use **`xxd -ps`** to get the secrets the Access token got printed successfully, Refer below:-

**Code:-**

```yaml
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      # Checkout code
      - uses: actions/checkout@main

      # Log into Azure
      - uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

      - name: "Run az commands"
        run: |
              access_token=$(az account get-access-token --resource=${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }} --scope=https://management.azure.com/.default --query accessToken -o tsv)
              echo "Access Token: $access_token" | xxd -ps
```

**Output:-**

[image]

> Also, According to this **[SO
> answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73476075/how-to-not-mask-output-in-github-actions)  By mclayton** As long as you're authenticating with {{AZURE_CREDENTIALS}} stored in { and } in github secrets the value of secrets will be masked  by default you need to convert the value into base64 or something else to view it.

***By default Azure github action will mask the output of the secrets and Access token that is generated by the az account get-access-token command as a security measure:-***

**Code :-**

```yaml
on: [push]
name: Deploy ARM Template
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      # Checkout code
      - uses: actions/checkout@main

      # Log into Azure
      - uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

      - name: "Run az commands"
        run: |
              access_token=$(az account get-access-token --resource=${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }} --scope=https://management.azure.com/.default --query accessToken -o tsv)
              echo "Access Token: $access_token"
```

**Output:-**

[image]